# Why can't I load my Android 4.1 AVD?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I'm a bit new to Android developing. I followed the tutorials to set up Eclipse and created a 4.1 AVD, but when I attempt to launch the emulator it stops working. It simply gives me the shiny "Android" boot screen indefinitely. What should I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How long did you wait? The emulator can be rather quite slow. I personally recommend using an AVD of Android 2.X if you're not working with anything 4.1 specific. 3.X and up are excruciatingly slow for me.

Comment: I'm trying out the given solutions now. Let's see what happens.

Comment: @Romin - I was able to get a Android 2.3 AVD working and loaded a "Hello World!" app. Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

1) See if an older Android version AVD as suggested by Rob S. works for you ?

2) Did you delete the AVD and create a new one, just in case. Does it hang for those too ?

3) Killing adb instances is the next option before starting the AVD.

4) If you using Eclipse, try out starting the AVD with a Wipe User Data option.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

In the command line cd into android-sdks\platform tools and do an adb kill-server and adb start-server.

If the above fails, try:

-restarting the emulator

-restarting eclipse

-restating your computer